# Integrating Struts 2 and JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf, struts2, jsf-2.2

I have been trying to integrate Struts 2 and JSF 2.0 by using struts2-jsf-plugin, it seems not to work using facelets, I'm not sure if this plugin works with JSF 2.0 spec, when I used JSF integrated on JSP everthing works fine, but with Facelets, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot determine whether or not the request is stateless
com.sun.faces.renderkit.ServerSideStateHelper.isStateless(ServerSideStateHelper.java:497)
com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.isStateless(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:168)
com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:549)
com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:150)
org.apache.struts2.jsf.RestoreViewInterceptor.executePhase(RestoreViewInterceptor.java:98)
org.apache.struts2.jsf.FacesInterceptor.intercept(FacesInterceptor.java:62)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
org.apache.struts2.jsf.FacesSetupInterceptor.intercept(FacesSetupInterceptor.java:229)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
com.aritec.bank.filters.EmpresaSeleccionadaFilter.doFilter(EmpresaSeleccionadaFilter.java:101)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
```

I'm using struts2-core-2.3.16 and struts2-jsf-plugin-2.3.16 and jsf 2.2.6.

Has anyone run into this issue? I'm also using an old version of JBoss AS, it is 4.2.0, I wonder if that might be causing this problem. I'm using JDK 7. I configured Facelets Servlet on web.xml this way:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JspSupportServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts2.views.JspSupportServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I also have my action configured in struts.xml like this:

```
<package name="jsf" extends="jsf-default" namespace="/jsf">
    <result-types>
        <result-type name="jsf" class="org.apache.struts2.jsf.FacesResult"/>
    </result-types>

    <interceptors>
        <interceptor-stack name="jsfFullStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="params" />
            <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="jsfStack"/>
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>

    <default-interceptor-ref name="jsfFullStack"/>
    <action name="test" class="com.jsf.actions.JSFTestAction" method="test">
        <result name="success" type="jsf"/>
    </action>
</package>
```

Since JSF 2.0 doesn't need a view handler I have an empty faces-config.xml.